# A simple method to execute Entity Framework Core queries in parallel

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, entity-framework-core, linq-expressions

As you might know, EF Core does not support executing multiple queries in parallel on the same context using something like `Task.WhenAll`.

So you have to write this code instead:

```
using var context1 = _factory.CreateDbContext();
using var context2 = _factory.CreateDbContext();
using var context3 = _factory.CreateDbContext();

var result1Task = context1.Set<T1>().ToListAsync();
var result2Task = context2.Set<T2>().ToListAsync();
var result3Task = context3.Set<T3>().ToListAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(result1Task, result2Task, result3Task);

var result1 = result1Task.Result;
var result2 = result2Task.Result;
var result3 = result3Task.Result;
```

To get rid of all these using statements, I started writing a library which exposes a `Set<TEntity()` extension method on `IDbContextFactory<TContext>`. You can use it like this.

```
var result1Task = _factory.Set<T1>().ToListAsync();
var result2Task =  _factory.Set<T2>().ToListAsync();
var result3Task =  _factory.Set<T3>().ToListAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(result1Task, result2Task, result3Task);

var result1 = result1Task.Result;
var result2 = result2Task.Result;
var result3 = result3Task.Result;
```

To achieve this, it heavily relies on reflection and EF Core internals. And because of this, I would really like a code review from someone experienced with EF Core, Expressions and IQueryable.

What it basically does is, it creates an `IQueryable<TEntity>` which is then exchanged for a real `DbSet<TEntity>` once it is executed and immediately disposes the context after that. When using the async version, it is a bit more complex. It passes down the `DbContext` to the `AsyncEnumerator` and disposes the context together with the `AsyncEnumerator`.

You can find the whole project on Github too
https://github.com/wertzui/EntityFrameworkCore.Parallel

Tank you in advance.

DbContextFactoryExtensions.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains the <see cref="Set{TContext, TEntity}(IDbContextFactory{TContext})"/> extension method wich is the starting point for any query.
/// </summary>
public static class DbContextFactoryExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The starting point for your query. Make sure <typeparamref name="TEntity"/> is available as a <see cref="DbSet{TEntity}"/> on your <typeparamref name="TContext"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TContext">The type of the <see cref="DbContext"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type fo the entities.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="contextFactory">The factory which can create the <see cref="DbContext"/>.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> Set<TEntity>(this IDbContextFactory<DbContext> contextFactory)
        //where TContext : DbContext
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var query = new EntityQueryable<TEntity>(
            new QueryProvider(new DbContextFactoryQueryContext<TEntity>(contextFactory)),
            new EntityType<TEntity>());
        return query;
    }
}
```

EntityType.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a minimal implementation of <see cref="IEntityType"/> to support the creation of queries without the need of a DbContext.
/// Most of its methods will just throw exceptions.
/// When the query is actually executed, the expression which is started with this class is replaced to contain an instance of the implementation from the real Entity Framework library.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type of the entities in the DbSet.</typeparam>
public class EntityType<TEntity> : IEntityType
{
    public object this[string name] => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IEntityType BaseType => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string DefiningNavigationName => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IEntityType DefiningEntityType => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IModel Model => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string Name => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Type ClrType => typeof(TEntity);

    public bool HasSharedClrType => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public bool IsPropertyBag => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IAnnotation FindAnnotation(string name) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IForeignKey FindForeignKey(IReadOnlyList<IProperty> properties, IKey principalKey, IEntityType principalEntityType) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IIndex FindIndex(IReadOnlyList<IProperty> properties) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IIndex FindIndex(string name) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IKey FindKey(IReadOnlyList<IProperty> properties) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IKey FindPrimaryKey() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IProperty FindProperty(string name) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IServiceProperty FindServiceProperty(string name) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public ISkipNavigation FindSkipNavigation(string name) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IEnumerable<IAnnotation> GetAnnotations() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IEnumerable<IForeignKey> GetForeignKeys() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IEnumerable<IIndex> GetIndexes() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IEnumerable<IKey> GetKeys() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IEnumerable<IProperty> GetProperties() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IEnumerable<IServiceProperty> GetServiceProperties() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public IEnumerable<ISkipNavigation> GetSkipNavigations() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

QueryProvider.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// A basic query provider which will pass the execution logic down the the given <see cref="IQueryContext"/>.
/// </summary>
public class QueryProvider : IAsyncQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryContext _queryContext;
    private static readonly MethodInfo _genericCreateQueryMethod
        = typeof(QueryProvider)
            .GetRuntimeMethods()
            .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(CreateQuery) && m.IsGenericMethod);
    private readonly MethodInfo _genericExecuteMethod;

    public QueryProvider(IQueryContext queryContext)
    {
        _queryContext = queryContext;

        _genericExecuteMethod = _queryContext.GetType()
             .GetRuntimeMethods()
             .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(IQueryContext.Execute) && m.IsGenericMethod);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
        => (IQueryable)_genericCreateQueryMethod
            .MakeGenericMethod(expression.Type.GetSequenceType())
            .Invoke(this, new object[] { expression });

    public virtual IQueryable<T> CreateQuery<T>(Expression expression)
        => new EntityQueryable<T>(this, expression);

    public virtual object Execute(Expression expression)
        => _genericExecuteMethod
        .MakeGenericMethod(expression.Type)
            .Invoke(_queryContext, new object[] { expression });

    TResult IQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        => _queryContext.Execute<TResult>(expression);

    public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => _queryContext.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(expression, cancellationToken);
}
```

IQueryContext.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for a query context. A query context is the thing that will actually execute any query.
/// </summary>
public interface IQueryContext
{
    TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression query);
    TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

DbContextFactoryQueryContext.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// This class contains the logic which will actually create the <see cref="DbContext"/> and execute the query on it.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TContext"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TEntity"></typeparam>
public class DbContextFactoryQueryContext<TEntity> : DbContextFactoryQueryContext, IQueryContext
    //where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<DbContext> factory;

    public DbContextFactoryQueryContext(IDbContextFactory<DbContext> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression query)
    {
        using (var context = factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
            var set = context.Set<TEntity>();
            var queryaple = set.AsQueryable();
            var provider = queryaple.Provider;

            var replaced = ReplaceProvider(query, set, provider);
            var result = provider.Execute<TResult>(replaced);
            var buffered = Buffer(result);
            return buffered;
        }
    }

    private static Expression ReplaceProvider(Expression query, DbSet<TEntity> set, IQueryProvider provider)
    {
        var setQuery = provider is IAsyncQueryProvider asyncProvider ?
                            new QueryRootExpression(asyncProvider, set.EntityType) :
                            new QueryRootExpression(set.EntityType);
        Expression replaced;
        if (query is MethodCallExpression call)
            replaced = call.Update(call.Object, new Expression[] { setQuery }.Concat(call.Arguments.Skip(1)));
        else if (query is QueryRootExpression root)
            replaced = setQuery;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException($"An Expression of type {query.Type} is not supported.", nameof(query));
        return replaced;
    }

    private static TResult Buffer<TResult>(TResult result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (result is IEnumerable enumerable)
        {
            var type = enumerable.GetType();
            if (type.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1)
            {
                var genericArgument = type.GenericTypeArguments[0];

                var genericToList = _toListMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArgument);
                var list = genericToList.Invoke(null, new object[] { enumerable });

                var casted = (TResult)list;
                return casted;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // We cannot use a using block here, because the result will be enumerated after this method has already returned.
        // Instead we pass the DbContext down to the enumerator which will then dispose the context once itself gets disposed.
        // This will happen when the result is enumerated.
        var context = factory.CreateDbContext();
        try
        {
            context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
            var set = context.Set<TEntity>();
            var queryaple = set.AsQueryable();
            var provider = queryaple.Provider;

            if (provider is IAsyncQueryProvider asyncProvider)
            {
                var replaced = ReplaceProvider(query, set, provider);
                var result = asyncProvider.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(replaced);
                var buffered = BufferAsync(result, context, cancellationToken);
                return buffered;
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot execute an async query on a non async query provider.");
        }
        catch
        {
            context.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static TResult BufferAsync<TResult>(TResult result, IAsyncDisposable dbSet, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (result is IEnumerable enumerable)
        {
            var buffered = EntitiyFrameworkCore.Parallel.AsyncEnumerableExtensions.Buffer((dynamic)result, dbSet);
            return (TResult)buffered;
        }

        return result;
    }
}


public abstract class DbContextFactoryQueryContext
{
    protected static readonly MethodInfo _toListMethodInfo = typeof(Enumerable)
                    .GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.ToList));

    protected static readonly MethodInfo _toListAsyncMethodInfo = typeof(AsyncEnumerable)
                    .GetMethod(nameof(AsyncEnumerable.ToListAsync));

    protected static readonly MethodInfo _toAsyncEnumerableMethodInfo = typeof(AsyncEnumerable)
                    .GetMethods()
                    .Single(m =>
                    {
                        if (m.Name != nameof(AsyncEnumerable.ToAsyncEnumerable))
                            return false;

                        var parameter = m.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault();
                        if (parameter == null)
                            return false;

                        var parameterType = parameter.ParameterType;
                        if (!typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(parameterType))
                            return false;

                        return true;
                    });
}
```

DbContextFactoryQueryContext.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// This class contains the logic which will actually create the <see cref="DbContext"/> and execute the query on it.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TContext"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TEntity"></typeparam>
public class DbContextFactoryQueryContext<TEntity> : DbContextFactoryQueryContext, IQueryContext
    //where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<DbContext> factory;

    public DbContextFactoryQueryContext(IDbContextFactory<DbContext> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression query)
    {
        using (var context = factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
            var set = context.Set<TEntity>();
            var queryaple = set.AsQueryable();
            var provider = queryaple.Provider;

            var replaced = ReplaceProvider(query, set, provider);
            var result = provider.Execute<TResult>(replaced);
            var buffered = Buffer(result);
            return buffered;
        }
    }

    private static Expression ReplaceProvider(Expression query, DbSet<TEntity> set, IQueryProvider provider)
    {
        var setQuery = provider is IAsyncQueryProvider asyncProvider ?
                            new QueryRootExpression(asyncProvider, set.EntityType) :
                            new QueryRootExpression(set.EntityType);
        Expression replaced;
        if (query is MethodCallExpression call)
            replaced = call.Update(call.Object, new Expression[] { setQuery }.Concat(call.Arguments.Skip(1)));
        else if (query is QueryRootExpression root)
            replaced = setQuery;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException($"An Expression of type {query.Type} is not supported.", nameof(query));
        return replaced;
    }

    private static TResult Buffer<TResult>(TResult result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (result is IEnumerable enumerable)
        {
            var type = enumerable.GetType();
            if (type.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1)
            {
                var genericArgument = type.GenericTypeArguments[0];

                var genericToList = _toListMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArgument);
                var list = genericToList.Invoke(null, new object[] { enumerable });

                var casted = (TResult)list;
                return casted;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // We cannot use a using block here, because the result will be enumerated after this method has already returned.
        // Instead we pass the DbContext down to the enumerator which will then dispose the context once itself gets disposed.
        // This will happen when the result is enumerated.
        var context = factory.CreateDbContext();
        try
        {
            context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
            var set = context.Set<TEntity>();
            var queryaple = set.AsQueryable();
            var provider = queryaple.Provider;

            if (provider is IAsyncQueryProvider asyncProvider)
            {
                var replaced = ReplaceProvider(query, set, provider);
                var result = asyncProvider.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(replaced);
                var buffered = BufferAsync(result, context, cancellationToken);
                return buffered;
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot execute an async query on a non async query provider.");
        }
        catch
        {
            context.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static TResult BufferAsync<TResult>(TResult result, IAsyncDisposable dbSet, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (result is IEnumerable enumerable)
        {
            var buffered = EntitiyFrameworkCore.Parallel.AsyncEnumerableExtensions.Buffer((dynamic)result, dbSet);
            return (TResult)buffered;
        }

        return result;
    }
}


public abstract class DbContextFactoryQueryContext
{
    protected static readonly MethodInfo _toListMethodInfo = typeof(Enumerable)
                    .GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.ToList));

    protected static readonly MethodInfo _toListAsyncMethodInfo = typeof(AsyncEnumerable)
                    .GetMethod(nameof(AsyncEnumerable.ToListAsync));

    protected static readonly MethodInfo _toAsyncEnumerableMethodInfo = typeof(AsyncEnumerable)
                    .GetMethods()
                    .Single(m =>
                    {
                        if (m.Name != nameof(AsyncEnumerable.ToAsyncEnumerable))
                            return false;

                        var parameter = m.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault();
                        if (parameter == null)
                            return false;

                        var parameterType = parameter.ParameterType;
                        if (!typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(parameterType))
                            return false;

                        return true;
                    });
}
```

SharedTypeExtensions.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains extension methods to find the generic type parameter of a collection type.
/// </summary>
internal static class SharedTypeExtensions
{
    public static Type GetSequenceType(this Type type)
    {
        var sequenceType = TryGetSequenceType(type);
        if (sequenceType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The given type is not a collection type", nameof(type));
        }

        return sequenceType;
    }

    public static Type TryGetSequenceType(this Type type)
        => type.TryGetElementType(typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            ?? type.TryGetElementType(typeof(IAsyncEnumerable<>));
    public static Type TryGetElementType(this Type type, Type interfaceOrBaseType)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var types = GetGenericTypeImplementations(type, interfaceOrBaseType);

        Type singleImplementation = null;
        foreach (var implementation in types)
        {
            if (singleImplementation == null)
            {
                singleImplementation = implementation;
            }
            else
            {
                singleImplementation = null;
                break;
            }
        }

        return singleImplementation?.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetGenericTypeImplementations(this Type type, Type interfaceOrBaseType)
    {
        var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
        if (!typeInfo.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        {
            var baseTypes = interfaceOrBaseType.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface
                ? typeInfo.ImplementedInterfaces
                : type.GetBaseTypes();
            foreach (var baseType in baseTypes)
            {
                if (baseType.IsGenericType
                    && baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceOrBaseType)
                {
                    yield return baseType;
                }
            }

            if (type.IsGenericType
                && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceOrBaseType)
            {
                yield return type;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetBaseTypes(this Type type)
    {
        type = type.BaseType;

        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;

            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To those encountering this question in the close queue, the issue has been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All public API surfaces should validate input parameters.

---

Restricting the queries to a single entity type seems limiting. You can't join entities with no navigation properties.

---

It fails when using navigation properties (C# 9/EF Core 5.0):

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<TestDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("hest"));

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var factory = provider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<TestDbContext>>();

using (var db = provider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<TestDbContext>>().CreateDbContext())
{
    await db.Ones.AddRangeAsync(
        Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                  .Select(i => new Entity1 { Value = (i * 2).ToString(), Entity2 = new Entity2 { Value = (i * 7).ToString(), } }));
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}

// Fails when rewriting the query
var fails = await factory.Set<Entity1>()
              .Select(t => t.Entity2)
              .Select(t => t.Entity1)
              .ToListAsync();

// Can't join two DbSets with different contexts.
var test = await factory.Set<Entity1>()
                        .Join(factory.Set<Entity2>(), e1 => e1.ID, e2 => e2.ID, (e1, e2) => e2.Value)
                        .ToListAsync();

public class Entity1
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext([NotNull] DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Entity1> Ones { get; protected set; }
    public DbSet<Entity2> Twos { get; protected set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity2>()
                    .HasOne(e => e.Entity1)
                    .WithOne(e => e.Entity2)
                    .HasPrincipalKey<Entity1>(e => e.ID)
                    .HasForeignKey<Entity2>(e => e.ID);
    }
}
```

---

If a slightly uglier API is acceptable the whole thing can be implemented with a single extension method:

```
public static class EFConcurrentQueryExtension
{
    public static async Task<TResult> ConcurrentAsync<TDbContext, TResult>(
        this IDbContextFactory<TDbContext> dbContextFactory,
        Func<TDbContext, Task<TResult>> asyncQuery)
        where TDbContext : DbContext
    {
        if (dbContextFactory is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContextFactory));
        }

        if (asyncQuery is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(asyncQuery));
        }

        using var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        var result = await asyncQuery(context);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And the example would look like:

```
var result1Task = _factory.ConcurrentAsync(ctx => ctx.Set<T1>().ToListAsync());
var result2Task = _factory.ConcurrentAsync(ctx => ctx.T2.ToListAsync());
var result3Task = _factory.ConcurrentAsync(ctx => ctx.Set<T3>().ToListAsync());

await Task.WhenAll(result1Task, result2Task, result3Task);

var result1 = await result1Task;
var result2 = await result2Task;
var result3 = await result3Task;
```

Comment: Thanks for the review! I'll try to fix the problem with the navigation properties. I know that `Join()` is not working and that is acceptable. Also the "uglier API" is not acceptable as I want to keep the syntax equal to what everybody knows from a normal EF query.

Comment: For anyone interested: The first (and fixed) version is now available on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Parallel/